# Horizontal scroll bar in panel-body bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

I am using a panel within that panel I am using div's with list-group ofcourse it will stack evantually but I want it that is has a horizontal scroll bar. I already tried using `overflow` this is not succesfully.

Shown below is the code that I am using:

```html
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="panel panel-flat ">
                                <div class="panel-heading">
                                    <h6 class="panel-title">Gebruikers</h6>
                                    <div class="heading-elements">
                                        <ul class="icons-list">
                                            <li><a data-action="collapse"></a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="panel-body ">
                                        @foreach($permlist as $list)
                                            <div class="col-md-3" >
                                                <div class="content-group">
                                                    <h6 class="text-semibold heading-divided"><i class="icon-folder6 position-left"></i>
                                                        {{$list->name}} </h6>
                                                    <div class="list-group no-border">
                                                        @foreach($permreq as $request)

                                                            @if($request->state == $list->short_name)
                                                                <a href="{{route('permission.manage.details.user', $request->id)}}" class="list-group-item ">
                                                                    <i ></i>{{ $request->requester }} voor {{$request->name}}
                                                                    @if(isset($request->tags))
                                                                        @foreach(json_decode($request->tags) as $tag)
                                                                            @foreach($permlabel as $label)
                                                                                @if($label->short_name == $tag)
                                                                                    <span class="label" style="background-color: {{$label->color}}">&nbsp;</span>
                                                                                @endif
                                                                            @endforeach
                                                                        @endforeach
                                                                    @endif
                                                                </a>
                                                            @endif
                                                        @endforeach
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        @endforeach
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: set a width to the div.For e.g. `width:100px;` and use `overflow-x:auto;`.

Comment: After adding this it does not add a scroll bar it still stacks the div's